# How to create a filtered search with check_box_tag on a HABTM association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble creating the check boxes that will filter out the organizations according to categories. Each Service Provider has and belongs to many service categories.

**Model:**

*service_provider.rb*

```
class ServiceProvider < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :mission, :image_url, :website, :providers_email ,:street1 ,
      :street2,:city, :state, :zip_code, :work_phone, :fax,:infraction_supported, :other,
      :contact_person, :contact_email, :service_category_ids

      has_and_belongs_to_many :service_categories
      has_and_belongs_to_many :infractions
      has_and_belongs_to_many :referrals
      has_many :users



  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ? OR mission LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%" )
    else
      scoped
    end
  end


end
```

*service_category.rb*

```
class ServiceCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :service_providers
end
```

**View:**

```
<body id="service-provider-all">

  <section class="container">
    <div class="content row">

     <section class="left-sidebar col col-lg-2">
      <h2> Search Here</h2>


      <%= form_tag user_service_providers_path, :method => :get do %>

      <p>
       <%= label_tag(:search, "Search for service provider by name:") %>
       <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>

       <%= label_tag :service_category %>
       <% @service_categories.each do |service_category|  %>
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <%= check_box_tag "service_provider[service_category_ids][]", 
           service_category.id, false, :id => "service_category_id_#{service_category.id}" %>
          <%= service_category.name.capitalize %>
        </label>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </p>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    <% end %>

  </section> <!-- left-sidebar col col-lg-2 -->

  <section class="main col col-lg-7">

    <div id="service-providers-list">

      <%= render 'service_providers_list' %>

   </div>
  </section> <!-- main col col-lg-6 -->

  <section class="sidebar col col-lg-3">
    <h2> Side Bar </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, libero tempore 
    iure quas eum sed nihil error similique. Est, nam, nesciunt unde quaerat aut 
    expedita enim quasi! Facilis, quasi, asperiores.</p>

  </section> <!-- right sidebar -->
</div>  <!-- content -->
</section> <!-- container -->
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
class ServiceProvidersController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @service_providers = ServiceProvider.search(params[:search]).order("service_providers.created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
    @service_categories = ServiceCategory.all

  end

  def new
    @user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    @service_categories = ServiceCategory.all
    @service_provider = ServiceProvider.new
  end

  def create
    @service_provider = ServiceProvider.new(params[:service_provider])
   if @service_provider.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Service Provider created.'
      redirect_to user_service_providers_url
   else
     flash[:notice] = 'Service Provider not created.'
     render :new
   end
 end


 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   @service_provider = ServiceProvider.find(params[:id])
 end

 def edit
 end

def cbo
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
end
```

**Routes:**

```
Weintervene::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'welcome#index'

  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup' => 'users#create'
  get '/login', to: 'session#new'
  post '/login' => 'session#create'
  get '/logout' => 'session#destroy'

  match '/demo', to: 'users#demo'
  match 'users/1/template', to: 'users#template'
  post 'posts' => 'service_providers#create'



  resources :schools do
    resources :users
    resources :students
  end

  resources :users do
    match '/referrals/new_no_pic' => 'referrals#new_no_pic', as: :no_pic
    match '/service_providers/cbo' => 'service_providers#cbo', as: :cbo
    resources :referrals
    resources :incident_logs
    resources :service_providers
    resources :students
    resources :service_categories
  end

   resources :students do
    resources :referrals
    resources :incident_logs
  end
end
```